# How to call the function in DataTable script

Tags: javascript, google-maps, datatables

I want to call the function with arguments and its return values to datatable. and that value is shown in datatable td

```
"mData": "address",
            "fnRender": function ( obj ) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(obj.aData['latitude'], obj.aData['longitude']);
                geocoder.geocode({
                    'latLng': latlng
                }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if (results[0]) {
                            var address = results[0].formatted_address;
                            console.log(address);
                            return address;
                            callback(address);
                        } else {
                            alert('No results found');
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                    }


                });
```

Here address is shown in data Table. which is in mData. how to assign that

Comment: So, what's the issue?

Comment: You're trying to return a value from an asynchronous call but your function will have finished before that...

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous, you can't "return" a value from it.  You need to use the value in the callback function.

Comment: How to use callback function and shows the data

Comment: is your `fnRender` call `getAddress()` ?

Comment: I have edited my question .. check above